# Removing Highchart datalabels on windows resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, charts, highcharts

I have been trying to implement the pie chart using Highcharts but am encountering an issue with the datalabels on very low resolutions being cropped.

I have attempted adding a windows.resize withing the formatter: function() but that failed.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
           // Radialize the colors
            Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
                return {
                    radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, color],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                    ]
                };
            });

            // Build the chart
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                    stops: [

                     ]
                  },                        
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Header Here'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                    percentageDecimals: 0
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: false,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +'%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Votes',
                    data: [
                        ['Vote One', 50],                   
                        ['Vote Two', 50],
                        ['Vote three', 2]
                    ]
                }]
            });
```

Is there anyway other than creating a new chart on resize that the labels can be set to false / hidden? and shown again above a certain resolution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set useHTML as true for datalabels and in formatter define your own divs. Then when you catch resize event use show / hide functons.

Simple example which show/hide datalabels after click button is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VYGEW/

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<div class="datalabel">' + this.y + '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    }, function (chart) {

        $('#btn').toggle(function () {

            $('.datalabel').hide();
        }, function () {
            $('.datalabel').show();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Brilliant, pretty simple fix! Appreciate your help :)