# Response highcharts datalabels on series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been working with http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels

And my current set up for labels looks like this:

```
plotOptions = {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter() {
              if(this.y != 0) {
                return formatValue(this.y, prefix, suffix);
              }
            }
        }
      }
};
```

But the problem I have is that if my column chart has let's say 30 columns, all of the labels run into each other. I see that I can set the allowOverlap param to false and so then they would not overlap....but then it looks messy with data labels all over the chart to prevent overlap. Is there a way to configure my highcharts to just hide all datalabels if there are too many labels (too many overlaps to handle)?

I've taken a look at [Removing Highchart datalabels on windows resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751547/removing-highchart-datalabels-on-windows-resize) but ideally would like to see if highcharts handles this.

Comment: Hey es3735746 I was looking through your code and would like some clarification on what you mean by 'would like to see if highcharts handles this?'

I'd like to help in any way I can.

Comment: You can extend Highcharts, modify methods responsible from hiding overlapping labels http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts - but I am not sure what you are after, what do you mean by 'too many overlaps to handle'?